# How can I automatically correct the UNC file path of linked workbooks when one of the workbooks changes paths, in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two workbooks, Source.xlxs and Linked.xlsx. In Source I have a tab that has linked cells, in the form of array formulas,  to cells in a tab, TabName, in Linked. The formula in Source looks something like this {='[Linked.xlsx]TabName'!$B$3:$D$10)}. When Linked gets moved, the formula changes to something like this {='htttps://site.com/sites/Site791/Root/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/[Linked.xlsx]'!$B$3:$D$10)}, where the UNC file path is the original file path of the Linked workbook, therefore effectively breaking the connection to the actual workbook in it's new location.

Is there a way for me to set up a cell that I input the new file path into and it automatically corrects the updated file path. I want to avoid having to do a Find and replace every time this happens, but rather enter the new file path (or piece of it) into a cell that the UNC can refer to.

Comment: Take a look at the build-in features: [Find links (external references) in a workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-links-external-references-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1); [Break a link to an external reference in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-links-external-references-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1) and  [Description of link management and storage in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328440/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You want to use the `INDIRECT()` function.

Basically, you pick a cell that will have any changeable portion of the path name/filename/sheetname/so on. THAT is where you will enter the new information once you know it.

Then you use string techniques to create a string using that changeable information and any that is not routinely changing that would result in a final string that is a proper, acceptable to Excel, path/filename/etc.

Once you have the full, exactly right, string produced, you "wrap" it with the `INDIRECT()` function ("wrap" means pretty much you just put it into the ()'s of the function).

`INDIRECT()` will turn the string from a useless string to an actual cell address. Or range address. Excel then uses that address or range address in whatever function it is in as the address or range address for that function. So you now have a place where you can make a single change in the address information (one you can paste in, by the way) so no mis-typing, and have it reflected into a million formulas.

Now... given your need, that string will be pretty long, and the resulting formula that JUST creates the range address will be even longer. Picture pasting that into a ton of formulas, maybe several times for each. Even `Finds and Replace` could feel obnoxious. You can, however, create a simple Named Range like "UNC_Path" in which you put all that muck, once you have it nice and solid. Then build out your formulas using that Named Range for the range address and never have to make changes to the formulas themselves, just the one place you put the changebale information. Which can itself be in a Named Range so you don't need a cell somewhere for it. Harder for a user to step all over it too, when not in some cell somewhere.

But it's really that simple.

A further consideration though:  `INDIRECT()` will NOT read into a closed file. There are ways around this, one very simple one, but it would be complicated beyond belief to go much into it without some exact information about your use here. And being able to ask questions to clear this and that up. So if the linked file would be closed, that's a concern, but it's doable. Just need more information to simplify the answer.